# Taylor Polynomial of $f(x,y) = \sin(e^x-y)$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, \ f(x,y) = \sin(e^x-y)$. What the quickest/a quick way to find its taylor polynomial of degree $3$ around the point $(0, \pi)$?

EDIT: More context... It is, of course, possible to just compute the derivatives but that seems kind of ugly. I'm looking for a more elegant way - possibly using the well-known Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$.

Comment: What do you mean, "in $(0,\pi)$"?

Comment: Perhaps just compute the Taylor expansion of $\sin(t)$ around $1-\pi$.  Substitute $e^x-y$ for $t$.  Substitute the Taylor expansion for $e^x$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I assume that $(0,\pi)$ is the center of the expansion.  So, "in" should be "at"

Comment: I see. It's probably more common to call it the expansion "at" $(0,\pi)$ or "centered at", or "around" $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: To be fair, I first thought it meant "in the interval $(0,\pi)$" which was confusing given two variables. It's supposed to be "around $(x,y) = (0,\pi)$"

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I'm not a native speaker. Point taken. I mean the point $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: No worries, OP. You seem a lot more fluent than I would be if I tried to ask math questions in a language other than my L1!

Comment: haha thanks, though of course, it's an unfair advantage, as English is used everywhere

Comment: @MichaelBurr How exactly would it help on find the multivariate Taylor? Don't we still have $e^x$ terms after substituting $e^x-y$ into the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ at $1-\pi$?

Comment: But then substitute the Taylor expansion for $e^x$.

Comment: Ahhhh, indeed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x = 0 + a, y = \pi + b$. We can try the "brute force" method, i.e. using the definition of the multivariate Taylor series

$$ f(a,\pi + b) = f(0,\pi) + f_x (0,\pi)a + f_y(0,\pi)b + f_{xx}(0,\pi)\frac{a^2}{2!} + f_{xy}(0,\pi)ab + f_{yy}(0,\pi)\frac{b^2}{2!} \\
+ f_{xxx}(0,\pi)\frac{a^3}{3!} + f_{xxy}(0,\pi)\frac{a^2b}{2!} + f_{xyy}(0,\pi)\frac{ab^2}{2!} + f_{yyy}(0,\pi)\frac{b^3}{3!} $$

The derivatives shouldn't be difficult to compute
\begin{align} 
f_x(x,y) &= e^x\cos(e^x-y) \\
f_y(x,y) &= -\cos(e^x-y) \\
f_{xx}(x,y) &= e^x\cos(e^x-y) - e^{2x}\sin(e^x-y) \\
f_{xy}(x,y) &= e^x\sin(e^x-y) \\
f_{yy}(x,y) &= -\sin(e^x-y) \\
f_{xxx}(x,y) &= e^x\cos(e^x-y) - 3e^{2x}\sin(e^x-y) - e^{3x}\cos(e^x-y) \\
f_{xxy}(x,y) &= e^x\sin(e^x-y) + e^{2x}\cos(e^x-y) \\
f_{xyy}(x,y) &= -e^x\cos(e^x-y) \\
f_{yyy}(x,y) &= \cos(e^x-y)
\end{align}

There might be quicker ways, but this is the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Indeed, I did the same. It just seems kind of ugly, so I was hoping for a "better" method. Thanks for your answer, it's well written up!